# React - How to get the value form Materialize's Switches?

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I'm using switches component (designed by Materialize) inside React components, and I'd like to know, how could I get the value when the user has changed the switch (on/of).

```
<div className="switch right">
    <label>
    Any
    <input type="checkbox" onChange={() => alert('changed')}/>
    <span className="lever"></span>
    All
    </label>
</div>
```

I tried to set a onChange event to verify if I can, at least, get when it's triggered.

Answer (score 0):

As a start, I would recommend using react-materialize, which has been written into components for react here https://react-materialize.github.io/#/forms.

I guess the problem is that onChange works only for JSX, and from your code it looks like you are using plain HTML?

I have added your onChange event into my JSX and it works as expected.

If you used react-materialize, your code would look something like this:

```
<Input name='on' type='switch' onLabel='Any' offLabel='All' onChange={() => alert('changed')}/>
```

Comment: any way to get the "checked" value ?

Comment: I'd guess it would be the value prop, which would be true or false. I'm sure there is a param on the onChange function that would also show this